# Add Spacing between table rows

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, datagrid

I developed a data grid but I'm having some problems with customizing it.

Is there a way to remove the header bottom border and add a space between each row in the table?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qay2gw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**code**

```
<dx-data-grid style="margin-top:50px" class="table" [dataSource]="datas"
    [showColumnLines]="false" [showRowLines]="false" [columnAutoWidth]="true" [allowColumnResizing]="true">
    <dxo-header-filter [visible]="true"></dxo-header-filter>
    <dxi-column dataField="ID" dataType="text" caption="ID"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Name" dataType="text" caption="Name"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add some space between rows, try to change the number of px in the dx.light.css file in this engy

```
.dx-datagrid .dx-row > td {padding: 7px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This increases the size of the line and not the spacing between them

Answer (score 0):

for increasing the space between the rows, u have to increase the `padding` here:

```
.table .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-row > td { 
   padding: 7px 0;
}
```

this seems like it would only increase the size of the line, like u noticed but it's also increases the space.
Currently it looks like its not, because of the shadow which you set here:

```
.table .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-row {
   ..
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
}
```

Giving the `td` elemente padding, is maybe the only way to increase your spacing. You have to set the shadow somewhere else.

To remove the border at the top, try this:

```
.dx-datagrid-headers + .dx-datagrid-rowsview {
   border-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It didn't work properly or the border top disappeared :( The lines I intend for them to "separate". I tested this :: ng-deep .table .dx-datagrid-content .dx-datagrid-table {
  border-collapse: unset! important;
  border-spacing: 0px 16px! important;
} I got what I want but I don’t know if it’s right to use unset

Answer (score 0):

You can use **the `::ng-deep` pseudo-class selector**

`::ng-deep` manipulations are actually [**deprecated**](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), **BUT** it stills working for now.

In Fact `::ng-deep` is often necessary when you didn't write the component and don't have access to its source so feel free to use it for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-bottom: 4px solid #FFFFFF;` at .dx-data-row to add space between the table rows